# Inverse of a vector of functions

Tags: real-analysis

I know how can I find the inverse of a function , but I am really confused when I deal with a vector of functions

Suppose I have this vector :

$$ g(x_1,x_2)= \begin{bmatrix} x_1 +x_2\\x_2-x_1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Then the inverse will be :
$$\begin{bmatrix} (y1-y2)/2\\(y1+y2)/2\end{bmatrix}$$

I can just think in a stupid way , I thought the inverse will be 
$$\begin{bmatrix} y_1+y_2\\y_2-y_1\end{bmatrix}$$

Please can someone explain me and show the steps by which we got the inverse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ can be represented by the system of equations

$$\begin{align*} y_1 & = x_1 + x_2 \\ y_2 & = x_1-x_2 \end{align*}$$

Inverting $g$ is thus equivalent to solving this system of equations for $x=(x_1,x_2)$. Adding these equations, we find

$$2x_1=y_1+y_2$$

Subtracting the second from the first, we find

$$2x_2=y_1-y_2$$

Hence, we have

$$g^{-1}(y) = x = \pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2} = \pmatrix{\frac{y_1+y_2}{2} \\ \frac{y_1-y_2}{2}}$$